# IEnumerable<Model> returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having difficulty passing an `IEnumerable` as a model. The data is populating a form on one page - and doing so correctly. Upon submission the model returns as null.

I've seen various posts on this and they mostly reference naming-conventions so I have attempted different methods of naming the parameters to try to avoid any confusion in the model binding.

I have also tried various models and helpers to try and pass the data and all have the same result.

Current implementation:

Models:

```
public class UserProfileListModel
{
    public IEnumerable<UserProfileViewModel> UserProfileViewModels { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    public Role UserRole { get; set; }
    public Team UserTeam { get; set; }
    public Scope UserScope { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Project.WebUI.Models.UserPRofileListModel
```

*SNIP*

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Administrate Users:</legend>
    <table class="adminTbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>UserName:</th>
                <th>Role:</th>
                <th>Team:</th>
                <th>Scope:</th>
                <th>Update:</th>
                <th>Delete:</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{foreach (var user in Model.UserProfileViewModels)
              {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>@user.UserProfile.UserName
                            @{if (!user.UserProfile.Membership.IsConfirmed)
                              {
                                  using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Account", FormMethod.Post, null)){
                                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                @Html.Hidden("Token", user.UserProfile.Membership.ConfirmationToken)
                                @Html.Hidden("Name", user.UserProfile.UserName)
                              }
                            <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />}
                            }
                        </p>
                    </td>

                    @{using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUserChanges", "Account", FormMethod.Post, null))
                      {         
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.HiddenFor(u => user.UserProfile)
                          if (user.UserProfile.UserName != User.Identity.Name && user.UserProfile.Membership.IsConfirmed)
                          {
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(u => user.UserRole, Project.WebUI.Controllers.AccountController.RoleList, new { @class = "formdrop" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(u => user.UserTeam, Project.WebUI.Controllers.AccountController.TeamList, new { @class = "formdrop" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(u => user.UserScope, Project.WebUI.Controllers.AccountController.ScopeList, new { @class = "formdrop" })
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to update this user? ')" />
                            </td>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              /*If user is self or not yet confirmed these are here to buffer the delete button into the last cell*/
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { user.UserProfile.UserId }, new
                       {
                           onclick = "return confirm('Warning: Action cannot be undone. Are you sure you wish to permanently delete this entry?')"
                       })
                        </td>
                </tr>
              }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Controller:

Populate View:

```
    public ActionResult AdministrateUsers()
    {
        populateLists();

        var query = repository.UserProfiles.OrderBy(e => e.UserName);
        List<UserProfileViewModel> list = new List<UserProfileViewModel>();

        foreach(UserProfile up in query)
        {
            UserProfileViewModel vm = new UserProfileViewModel() { UserProfile = up };
            list.Add(vm);
        }

        UserProfileListModel models = new UserProfileListModel() 
        { 
           UserProfileViewModels = list.OrderBy(up => up.UserProfile.UserName)
        };

        return View(models);
    }
```

Accept Post:

```
    public ActionResult SaveUserChanges(UserProfileListModel model)
    {
        foreach (UserProfileViewModel upvm in model.UserProfileViewModels)
        {

            UserProfile up = new UserProfile()
            {
                UserId = upvm.UserProfile.UserId,
                UserEmail = upvm.UserProfile.UserName,
                UserName = upvm.UserProfile.UserName
            };

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repository.SaveUserProfile(up);
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }
```

The code does still need a lot of work but I can't get past getting the model back to the controller on post. I have also tried returning the UserProfileViewModel instead of the entire list.

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: "model" is null or "model.UserProfileViewModels" is null?

Comment: @jerther when attaching a debugger to the post-back the parameter being passed is null. This happens no matter which model I am trying to pass as long as it is/contains an ienumerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of invalid html including `form` elements as child elements of `tr` elements and duplicate `id` attributes. If you want to post back `UserProfileListModel` then you need a single `form` element and use an `EditorTemplate` or a `for` loop (not `foreach`) to render the controls so they are correctly named with indexers.

You are also trying to bind your dropdown lists to complex objects (for example `UserProfile`, `Role` etc.). `<select>` elements (and all form controls) only post back key/value pairs so you need to bind to a value type (for example `UserProfile.UserId`).

Your `SaveUserChanges()` post method is also trying access properties of `UserProfile` but you don't even have controls for properties of `UserProfile` in the form that post back to this method (for example `UserId = upvm.UserProfile.UserId, UserEmail = upvm.UserProfile.UserName, ...`) so they will always be null.

Answer (score 0):

You probalby need to bind properties in POST method like here:

```
  public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Subject,Text,IsImportant")] Announcment announcment) {... }
```

So it will be:

```
public ActionResult SaveUserChanges([Bind(Include = "UserProfile,Role,UserTeam,UserScope")]UserProfileListModel model)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that. I have tried unsuccessfully though using different combinations of models and includes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified your action method is for HTTP Post? And change your action method to accept UserProfileViewModels instead.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveUserChanges(UserProfileViewModels model)
{
```

You are also only posting back one model: UserProfileViewModels.
You have your form in your foreach loop, so each UserProfileViewModels has its own form. If you want to change it to post back your UserProfileListModel, move

```
@{using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUserChanges", "Account", FormMethod.Post, null))
```

outside of your foreach.

Comment: I do have:         [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] on the function. I have also moved the form around in different ways and using different models and it always returns null...